# Update the query onbeforeunload and

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, onbeforeunload, window.onunload

This is my First Query when `$_POST` is set:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['bags']))
{
    $bagS=$_POST['bags'];
        $id=$_POST["id"];
        $_SESSION['id']=$id;
        $cats = explode(" ", $bagS);
        $cats = preg_split('/,/', $bagS, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        foreach($cats as $key => $cat )
        {
        $cat  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$cats[$key]);
        $cat = trim($cat);
 if($cat !=NULL)
             {
                 $stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE wallet SET `Status`="Hold" where `Id`=? AND `bags`="'.$cat.'" ');
                 $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["id"]);
                 $stmt->execute();

  }
  }
}
```

After that is set the script timeout to update next query if nothing happen from user side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = "index.php?on_timeout=1"; }, 60 * 500);
</script>
```

Then script return query string when timeout and execute update query and redirect to  other page:

```
if(isset($_GET['on_timeout'])) {

   echo  $bagS=$_SESSION['bags'];
   echo $id=$_SESSION['id'];
        $cats = explode(" ", $bagS);
        $cats = preg_split('/,/', $bagS, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        foreach($cats as $key => $cat )
        {
        $cat  = mysql_real_escape_string($cats[$key]);
        $cat = trim($cat);
 if($cat !=NULL)
             {
                  $stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE wallet SET `Status`=" " where `Id`=? AND `bags`="'.$cat.'" AND `Status`="Hold" ');
                 $stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['id']);
                 $stmt->execute();
                 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>location.href = 'cards.php';</script>";

  }
  }
}

 ?>
```

Now I want to execute the same query on when user close the browser or back the browser with the help of `window.onbeforeunload`, so please tell me how set the update code in this event.

```
<script>
var areYouReallySure = false;
    function areYouSure() {
    if(allowPrompt){
        if (!areYouReallySure && true) {
            areYouReallySure = true;
            var confMessage = "are you sure to do this";
            return confMessage;
        }
    }else{
        allowPrompt = true;
    }
}

var allowPrompt = true;
window.onbeforeunload = areYouSure;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call you code before leaving the page

```
function myfoo(){
         // Write your logic here
           $.ajax({
            url: "Pageurl_that_having_your_update_code",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                on_timeout: 1
            },
            success: function (r) {}
});
    }
```

**onbeforeunload:**

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  myfoo();
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

**Or Jquery**

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  myfoo();
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

Comment: can u please tell me how to put this whole query in function myfoo()

Comment: @krishna myfoo() you can be used ajax and get the `isset($_GET['on_timeout'])` like above edit my code

Comment: thats what iam asking about sir.how can i use isset($_GET['on_timeout']) in ajax... iam confused how ajax get values..please help me

Comment: please see my above changes in `function myfoo(){}` As `data:{ on_timout:1}` request set there and you can get that update code that you will write as per above

Comment: using this ...function myfoo(){
   $.ajax({
            url: "index.php?on_timeout=1",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                on_timeout: 1
            },
            success: function (r) {}
});
     // Write your logic here
     console.log('hello');
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  myfoo();
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};

Comment: sorry for the late reply no need to pass in URL `url: "index.php?on_timeout=1` just url: "index.php

Comment: actually Sir .. on_timeout=1  is only for if user do nothing on page after timeout the query execute ..but i want to perform the same query without timeout when user click back or close browser button.but you use on_ timeout:1 in ajax

Comment: understood, in ajax You can pass **GET** and **POST**, as request we passed here data:{ XYZ:1} as per your convenience, and you have to find a response in index.php isset($_GET['XYZ']){//Exicuted}..so moral its just catch the request whatever you select name in `data:{ ABC:1}` Sorry for bad English.

Comment: as you see my full code on page .can you please change your code as per my condition? i need two variables which i have passing in url from last page $bagS=$_POST['bags']; and  $id=$_POST["id"];.. and one more question should i need to write  update code again like i wrote in if(isset($_GET['on_timeout'])) {
}?sir

Comment: shukriya anyway  for your precious time sir

Comment: if i add query params in beforeunload event handler, lets say I pressed browser "back" history button, would it go to the cached url + my new query param?